# Securing Client Access Token for Instagram

Tags: javascript, facebook, security, oauth, instagram

I'm currently building a small instagram feed on a page and need to request data from it's API to display posts. I do not have the access to add any server side code, so I will need to make all authorisations and requests to Instagram to the client side (a small JS script).

I see that FB developer offers a [Client Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/oembed/) which appears to enable such a thing. My question is two-fold:

1. Is this really secure? (I'm assuming it is as it is Oauth etc.)
2. As this token would be exposed, would others be able to simply copy the code and also display my posts on another page?

In the case of the last one, I am assuming this permission is read-only? I would not want others to be able to embed my posts in such a fashion either way...

Thanks

Comment: You can't give your accesstoken to other people. That of course would not be safe.

Comment: @WizKid The 'Client Access Token' offered by Facebook seems to me to state pretty clearly it can be used from the browser (if you read the docs). So anyone getting it would be getting it via the code, which of course would be possible as it is from the browser. My question is in regards to what can be done with this token (e.g. could someone gain access to FB/Instagram data through it or perform CRUD operations etc.)